# How to make Microsoft Single Tenant To work with STRAPI

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, strapi

Is there a way to setup Microsoft single tenant in Strapi as the Auth Provider?
I am current using the Multitenant settings since I have encountered unauthorized acess using the Single Tenant.
[image]

My objective is to used the Single Tenant since the users under the given organization must only have the accessed to login. Or is there a settings in Microsoft Azure Portal where I will used the Multitenant but limit the organization/team that will have accessed to login.

Comment: Sounds like you want to set that to single-tenant if you only want to allow a specific tenant. Your configuration in Strapi should include the tenant id in the authority/metadata address to ensure it also uses the single-tenant endpoint.

Comment: Hi juunas, thanks for your input. Do you have any resource or guide where I can follow through? Just my first time on using Strapi.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what that is at all.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to developing apps, developers can choose to configure their app to be either single-tenant or multi-tenant during app registration in the Azure portal.
•   Single-tenant apps are only available in the tenant they were registered in, also known as their home tenant.
•   Multi-tenant apps are available to users in both their home tenant and other tenants.
In your case if you want to change app from single tenant to multitenant  or vice versa you can change it from azure portal. By default, web app/API registrations in Azure AD are single tenant. You can change that finding the Supported account types switch on the Authentication pane of your application registration in the azure portal. Are you not getting this option?

In a single-tenant application, sign-in requests are sent to the tenant’s sign-in endpoint. For example, for contoso.onmicrosoft.com the endpoint would be: https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com. Requests sent to a tenant’s endpoint can sign in users (or guests) in that tenant to applications in that tenant.

With a multi-tenant application, the application doesn’t know up front what tenant the user is from, so you can’t send requests to a tenant’s endpoint. Instead, requests are sent to an endpoint that multiplexes across all Azure AD tenants: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common
single-tenant application normally takes an endpoint value like:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com
.and uses it to construct a metadata URL (in this case, OpenID Connect) like:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

or else you can also use tenant restriction to control the access to specific tenants. Please refer this to have more info [Use tenant restrictions to manage access to SaaS apps - Azure AD | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/tenant-restrictions)

[Tenancy in azure ad](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-and-multi-tenant-apps)

Comment: You don't answer the question, you're just exposing the difference between single tenant and multi tenant and this is a copy of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant ...